# Why is there a spec for min fall time in I2C Fast Mode?

Tags: i2c

Why is there a spec for min fall time in I2C Fast Mode but not in standard mode?
Is it fine to use I2C standard mode with a fall time of 5n?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Originally there was only Standard Mode with up to 100 kHz clock support. It did not have any specification for limiting the fall time speed and for compatibility this was never changed. But when the new Fast Mode that goes up to 400 kHz was specified, they specified slew rate limiting to reduce electromagnetic interference from the fast transitions.

Comment: Thank you
This make sense

Answer (score -1):

You may want to look at the application note from NXP, "UM10204 - I2C-bus specification and user manual". It has all the details you're looking for.

Comment: I have checked the NXP, "UM10204 - I2C-bus specification and from there only I got the doubt that "What could go wrong if i have a faster fall time while using I2C in Fast mode?"

Comment: The problem is that in Standard mode they allow faster fall time but not in Fast mode

Comment: UM10204 is published by the inventor of I2C. So if that's wrong maybe you should contact them directly and take it up with them instead of asking this forum !